# mysql/php - store html templates within the a database

Tags: php, mysql, html, templates, eval

I am wondering the best way to store html templates in a database where I am able to retrieve them and insert variables.

Obviously I could store them as php and then 'EVAL' the record.... but I heard it was evil.

is there a better way? :)

edit:

Sorry I wasn't clear... I tried to simplify it by saying html templates... what I really meant was small embed-able html elements (think youtube)... rather than an entire site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would also advice against storing the HTML inside the database. It's much more convenient to store them as templates on the file-system and include them or parse them when needed. I also recommend using something like Smarty. A very handy tool, that is.

However, if you would rather do it manually, here is what I would do.

First, I would store the template in a file on the file-system. If you would rather use a database, that can be done to. Just know that a database will, usually, cause more overhead when used for stuff like this.

For example, in the case of a YouTube video:

```
<object width="{$width}" height="{$height}">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/{$path}"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/{$path}"
           type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
           allowscriptaccess="always"
           allowfullscreen="true"
           width="{$width}" height="{$width}">
    </embed>
</object>
```

Then I would simply `str_replace` the PHP variables in there, much like PHP itself does with strings.

```
<?php
$template_path = 'templates/youtube_vid.tpl';
$template_data = file_get_contents($template_path);

$old = array('{$width}', '{$height}', '{$path}');
$new = array(425, 344, 'v/zuZB2O6orV0&hl=en_US&fs=1&');

echo str_replace($old, $new, $template_data);
?>
```

And that would be it.

You could of course use `<?php $width; ?>`-like placeholders and just `include` the template, but that leaves you at risk for injection attacks. This is the safer route.

Comment: I have decided to go with the <?php $width; ?> route... you and scrumpy jack are right... filesystem is the way to go with templates. I do not see how taking database data and directly inserting it with echo is anyway less secure then str_replacing the data in... I validate the data before I store it... its all alpha numeric or numeric so a simple enough to validate before inserting should make it safe enough right?

Comment: Sure, if you validate everything before including it, it should be fairly safe. If the template name is dynamic, remember to validate that to ;]

Answer (score 2):

Mark, do you need to store templates in the database? This will add a heavy burden to your DB server every time those templates are requested, unless you cache them.

Compare this to the filesystem which has built-in caches to streamline file reads.

Plus you won't have the potential security hole that may come from using eval().

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent the wheel, you can use a [templating](http://www.smarty.net) engine and store the templates themselves in a database. Personally I like to store templates in the file-system because it makes things **much** simpler to maintain, but its your project :)